# vega-lite: how to add a column starting from a datetime column

Tags: vega-lite

I have a source CSV with a datetime column (`2021-01-02T17:00:00`).

I would like to calculate a derived field, that contains only the month name (`%B`), "april","june", ecc..

How to do it?

[Here](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-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%20AHcCNYo1GxFmg1AWjGmFHrJ6oKc4NZ5r75khPUw4GIOXBPWJliGkGIxNYCNpdPoDAgEAYVAc7RBiCBVSBkFoANYaHBsbK-eA0MhYNAh32%20pS5mjWeiH49KOCXNiE6KBEAhJ8tGi6awaUmxeIGYLfQokAMbdbwqIDJ18cwcGOEAAEcGAuPwfhoUhfDoIEQCiGI7HiJJ2FSEZ30ybJcgiUUoBGY5QCOdo0HTQRPiUHACQfMg0CbZUl0sLUQDfD8NH-AoimA55QJQ8CEEg6CNHgxC6GQ1ClAlDQ3DYYYzASPo2AGRISImJRoEop8aLYOiRkYkBmOsVj2N9TilLYOFnBwNAAG1QD4wRP3QdVhikmDggQTdvl1JT0JgtRPm2FJkBeEAAFIACFFwUDz3y8jRfJQJSoICxBgpGND-BgrLFwAXSUKZrjS-j0Ei9Qcuk9BZDYBBskKpQzDIW9vKCcLZTsGgUr%20CigVALhEACp0zCQBgm0XeyQFiOFUJ4wyxufL9ZFsaDttvX5uJAbIdp6-aFuVIA) I use this CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply provide a transform with `timeFormat` [expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#timeFormat) as given below or in [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Y6aNlSlLITBVdW4hCUa9IdEAcgApAAhR91KxIHxvDowRcALpKMgWgANYaDgbDZL88A0GQWBoCGvq+kouY0NY9CIchShwJcbCEtEgQgCEREtDQujWBopKxPEBjBN8hRIAY0G4RUTGTr45g4MeACODAXH4Pw0KQvh0ECIBRDEdjxEk7CpCM5GZNkuQRKKu5AqARztGg6aCJ8Sg4ASBFkGgTbKkulhaiAZEURo9EFEUzHPKxwnsRuSiYFxvH8c8dBCSJHlicebhsMMZgJH0bADIkykTEo0AjMcmkZGwOkjPpICGdYxmmb65keWwcLODgW6gDZgiUeg96cdxdmIJB3y6oF-jHmonzbOeIroG+i4KGV5EVRo1UeV5dUIA1IyiS1Q0aoBShTNc-W2b+zz-iNtXoLIbAINkk1KGYZC4ZVQRBbKdg0L1fzqUlV3cMewxMGYSAME2i75SAsRwiJVkJRpxFUbItjcYDuG-JZIDZEDR2g29ypAA)

```
"transform": [{"calculate": "timeFormat(datum.data, '%B')", "as": "Month"}],
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why I cannot use `Month` as color field? If I use this, I have undefined legend https://gist.github.com/aborruso/99582744d9c8b1cd184da67af0af69d8

Comment: Inside the `data` config, `transform` is not allowed. If you check the configuration in vega-lite editor then you will see a yellow underline on transform which says property not allowed. Transform is supposed to be used outside. I have updated the editor link, so in that you will see the month in legend.